# Resizing buttons so they are all the same width

Tags: delphi

I have a "wide" TPanel with several buttons on it (essentially a tool bar).  All the buttons have Align=Left.  I have created a function which will resize the buttons to the same size and calculate the width of them so they fill the entire TPanel.  I call this function in the OnResize event handler of the TPanel.

```
procedure ScaleButtonsOnPanel;
var i: Integer;
begin
  for i:=0 to mPanel.ControlCount-1 do begin
      mPanel.Controls[i].Width := round(mPanel.width/mPanel.ControlCount-1)
  end;
end;
```

The problem is if I minimize and then restore the form the layout of the buttons change from the design layout.

Can anyone offer a solution to having buttons on a panel which can be resized but maintain the design time order (in terms of left to right placement) ?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the buttons should have their design time size or their resized size? Or you just want to resize the buttons except when the form is restored from it's minimized state?

Comment: At design time we layout the buttons to establish the order they should be in (left to right).  Size doesn't matter since they will be resized to fill the entire Panel at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean the "layout" changes? What layout are you talking about? In what way is it different?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: I think he means that the order of the buttons changes. This is a well-known annoyance associated with having two or more controls with the same `Align`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not really see your problem. But of course, you must set the position of the buttons, not only their size.

```
procedure TForm1.Panel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  btnWidth: integer;
begin
  btnWidth := Panel1.Width div Panel1.ControlCount;
  for i := 0 to Panel1.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    Panel1.Controls[i].Left := i * btnWidth;
    Panel1.Controls[i].Width := btnWidth;
  end;
end;
```

This works very well.

See https://privat.rejbrand.se/panelresize.wmv.

OK, now I see. I think the `alLeft` *is* actually your problem. Controls with the same align tend to change their order. This is a well-known Delphi annoyance. Do it like I do above, instead. Just make sure that you go through the buttons in the right order. If you cannot rely on the ordering of `Panel1.Controls`, then you can do like this: Set the `Tag` property of each toolbar button to its position (0, 1, ...) in the toolbar then do

```
procedure TForm1.Panel1Resize(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  btnWidth: integer;
begin
  btnWidth := Panel1.Width div Panel1.ControlCount;
  for i := 0 to Panel1.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    Panel1.Controls[i].Left := Panel1.Controls[i].Tag * btnWidth;
    Panel1.Controls[i].Width := btnWidth;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That was the purpose of the "Align=Left", so we didn't need to worry about setting the position.  They would just "fall into place".  When you loop over the controls can you be assured they go "left to right"?

Comment: OK. I see. But what in the world is the problem, then? :)

Comment: OK, now I see. I think the `alLeft` *is* actually your problem. Controls with the same align tend to change their order. This is a well-known Delphi annoyance. Do it like I do above, instead.

Comment: I will give this a try.  But I do have a "side" question: when looping over the controls it assumes the control with index 0 is the left most control, that associated with 1 is to the right of control index on 0.  Is this a valid assumption?  Or is it arbitrary?

Comment: I see - you are using the "Tag" property to deal with this.  But is there anyway not to rely on the "Tag" property?  This would cause double work for the developer.  We like to just use the align property during design to establish the order.  I guess I would have to write a pre-processor function which gets called before anything to find out the layout order.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to see if a [TFlowPanel](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/ExtCtrls.TFlowPanel) doesn't better suit your needs?

Comment: I will have to check that out.