# Resizing buttons with keeping the same width when some buttons are invisible

Tags: delphi, button, resize, visibility, invisible

I would like implement automatically resizing buttons keeping the same width when some buttons are invisible. I used code prepared by Andreas Rejbrand [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864182/resizing-buttons-so-they-are-all-the-same-width), but the issue is more complicated when I set some buttons invisible. In places where we have invisible buttons there are gaps. 
My idea is to check how many buttons are invisible and next set *btnWidth* depending on the amount of visible buttons. I don't actually know how I can check if buttons are invisible in this case.

I want to use *TAdvGlowButton* component for the buttons and *TPanel* component for the panel and add *OnResize* procedure to panel like below:

```
procedure TForm3.Panel4Resize(Sender: TObject);
var
   i: Integer;
   btnWidth: Integer;
begin
   btnWidth := Panel4.Width div Panel4.ControlCount;
   for i := 0 to Panel4.ControlCount - 1  do
      begin
         Panel4.Controls[i].Left := i * btnWidth;
         Panel4.Controls[i].Width := btnWidth;
      end;
end;
```

Could you give me any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: You need to replace `Panel4.ControlCount` with the number of visible controls instead, and then only set the width and left of those visible controls (not all of them). You'll have to track the number that are visible yourself, or loop through once first to count them before you loop through to resize/reposition them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm3.Panel4Resize(Sender: TObject);
const
  cLeftMargin = 10;  //Margin at the left side of the group of buttons
  cSpacing = 10;     //Spacing/Margin between the buttons
  cRightMargin = 10; //Margin at the right side of the group of buttons
var
   i, VisibleControls, lLeft: Integer;
   btnWidth: Integer;
begin
   //count number of visible controls
   VisibleControls := 0;
   for i := 0 to Panel4.ControlCount - 1  do
      if Panel4.Controls[i].Visible then
         inc(VisibleControls);

   btnWidth := (Panel4.Width-cLeftMargin-cRightMargin - cSpacing*(VisibleControls-1)) div VisibleControls;

   //distribute the visible controls
   lLeft := cLeftMargin;
   for i := 0 to Panel4.ControlCount - 1  do
      if Panel4.Controls[i].Visible then
      begin
         Panel4.Controls[i].Left := lLeft;
         Panel4.Controls[i].Width := btnWidth;
         lLeft := lLeft + btnWidth + cSpacing;
      end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for your smart idea, but I think about one more future - margins between buttons. I put this code to `procedure miResizeButtons(pnlToResize: TPanel)`to use it for other panels. Next I modified code with distributing the visible controls and added: `pnlToResize.Controls[i].Left := iVisibleButtons * (btnWidth + 1); pnlToResize.Controls[i].Width := btnWidth - 1; pnlToResize.Controls[i].Top := Panel4.Controls[0].Top; pnlToResize.Controls[i].Height := Panel4.Controls[0].Height;`. The only issue is that sometimes last button extends beyond the frame. Do you have any tip?

Comment: I have modified the answer to include left and right margins, and buttons spacing. You can simply adjust the const values.